# Did the device SDK update on my Toitbox just fail?

Tags: toit

I am using Toitware's platform for IoT. I just lost connectivity between my Toitbox and the console. How can I know whether the SDK update has completed as expected?

Answer (score 0):

That an SDK update is requested is indicated by an icon next to the device’s name in the console. The update will take place the next time the device comes online. At this point, an SDK update in progress is indicated by an OTA (Over The Air) progress bar on the Toitbox display. Note that the SDK version currently installed on a device is available from the console and the Toitbox display.

If the connectivity gets lost during the upgrade, the Toitbox display will indicate that the WiFi has been lost (barred WiFi symbol, or WiFi with a ?) and the progress bar of the update will stop. The update will restart as soon as the Toitbox comes online again.

If the SDK being updated is invalid, the console will automatically roll back to the previous installed SDK version. Messages in both logs and events tab will warn the user of this error. The currently installed version of the SDK is written on the Toitbox display.